# Setting a pointer to struct to equal to another pointer to struct returned by a function?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to build a linked list but for some reason my head is not updated properly. Here are the snippets of my code that are not working as I intended:

```
typedef struct node {
  int data;
  struct node *next;
} * node;

node create_node(int data) {
  node to_return = calloc(1, sizeof(struct node));
  to_return->data = data;
  to_return->next = NULL;
  return to_return;
}

int insert(int data, node head) {
  if (head == NULL) {
    head = create_node(data);
  }
  .
  .
  .
  }
  return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  node head = NULL;
  insert(1, head);

  printf("head->data: %d", head->data);
}
```

In this example, I'm trying to create the first node of the linked list using insert(). However, I'm getting a SEG fault, which means that the to_return node pointer returned by create_node() is not being set to the node head in insert() properly. What am I missing here?

EDIT: I double checked and head is getting set properly in insert(). The changes just don't persist for some reason

Comment: I am sorry but I'm still confused. I tried printing the head->data in insert() and I'm getting the right value but for some reasons that changes don't persist when  the program exits the function insert()

Comment: Also forgot to mention that node is a pointer to a struct.

Comment: **Never ever** ``typedef` pointers!

Comment: This looks like C. If you compile as C++, change the tag, but don't use tags for two different languages if this is not about inter-op between them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass a pointer to the node:

```
int insert(int data, node* head) {
  if (*head == NULL) {
    *head = create_node(data);
  }
  .
  .
  .
  }
  return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  node head = NULL;
  insert(1, &head);

  printf("head->data: %d", head->data);
}
```

(and btw that typedef is really confusing, since the insert function's second parameter is actually of type `struct node **`)

Answer (score 2):

In C and C++ all function parameters are passed by value, unless explicitly marked as by reference. This includes pointer parameters.

Your `insert` function is attempting to change the first parameter if the case that it is a null pointer. This will not work, as any changes made to the pointer will not pass from the function. You need to either pass a `node *head` or a `node& head` (in C++) to your `insert` function if you want to be ab le to change `head`.